# Laravel Support Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

Is laravel 3 have classes specially for handling Email, FTP, File upload, ZIP File, Captcha, Web service?
Or should be made its own class for the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with the power of [Bundles](http://bundles.laravel.com)! If they put every possible feature in the core then everyone's gonna whine how bloated the framework will be. So that's where bundles come in.

Here are some examples:

- [Captcha](http://bundles.laravel.com/search?q=captcha)
- [E-mail](http://bundles.laravel.com/search?q=mail)
- [OAuth](http://bundles.laravel.com/search?q=oauth)

The [Input class](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/input.php) has support for file uploads.

Comment: Ok ... I have seen it ..
Whether, if I want to make a class specially for WSDL handler can I register on laravel? In my applications I use the API to read the data. Before I use nusoap library when i use php native (not framework)